# useEffect shows setProjects is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when useEffect runs data gets fetched but when i put setProjects(data) it says:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setProjects is not a function
```

i have imported useState and UseEffect properly

export default function Projects() {

```
  const {projects, setProjects} = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    client.fetch('*[_type == "projects"]')
      .then((data) => {
        setProjects(data)
      })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
const {projects, setProjects} = useState([])
```

to this

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
```

Comment: wow thanks cant belive i wasted 30 minutes for this stupid problem

Comment: @Naveer  Have you considered Typescript, silly errors like this are found pretty much instantly..